# Boost spirit do not check for int overflow

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to parse some integers with boost spirit, and I have to check data for overflow and spirit doc says that all integer parsers do check for overflow, however it only works for unsigned types, if I try to parse signed integers spirit won't check for overflow anymore.

```
char const* b = "6600452345243524352340";
char const* e = b + strlen("6600452345243524352340");
int32_t res = 0;
bool valid = boost::spirit::qi::parse(b, e, boost::spirit::qi::int_, res);
std::cout << valid << " " << res << std::endl;
```

Is there a way to make spirit check for signed overflows? I am using boost 1.55, gcc 4.9.

Comment: what version of boost is this? What is the output you get and what output did you expect?

Comment: Like sehe shows in his answer Boost 1.60 does not have that problem, you should consider updating.

Comment: @sehe as I mentioned it is 1.55, looks like a bug in a boost spirit I just checked 1.56 and it works. I have to stick with 1.55, and will have to workaround the problem somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both check for overflow just fine:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d627e39ac926cbdb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using boost::multiprecision::int128_t;
using boost::multiprecision::int256_t;
using boost::multiprecision::uint128_t;
using boost::multiprecision::uint256_t;

template <typename T>
bool try_parse(char const* s) {
    auto b = s, e = b + strlen(s);
    T res = 0;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    bool valid = qi::parse(b, e, qi::int_parser<T, 10>(), res);
    if (!valid)
        std::cout << "Unparsed (" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ")\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Valid: " << res << "(" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ")\n";;

    if (b!=e)
        std::cout << " --> remaining: '" << std::string(b,e) << "'\n";

    return valid;
}

int main() {
    try_parse<int8_t>    ("6600452345243524352340");
    try_parse<uint8_t>   ("6600452345243524352340");

    try_parse<int16_t>   ("6600452345243524352340");
    try_parse<uint16_t>  ("6600452345243524352340");

    try_parse<int32_t>   ("6600452345243524352340");
    try_parse<uint32_t>  ("6600452345243524352340");

    try_parse<int64_t>   ("6600452345243524352340");
    try_parse<uint64_t>  ("6600452345243524352340");

    try_parse<int128_t>  ("6600452345243524352340");
    try_parse<uint128_t> ("6600452345243524352340");
}
```

Prints

```
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = signed char])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = unsigned char])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = short])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = unsigned short])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = int])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = unsigned int])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = long])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Unparsed (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = unsigned long])
--> remaining: '6600452345243524352340'
Valid: 6600452345243524352340 (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128, 128, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type::unchecked, void>, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option::et_off>])
Valid: 6600452345243524352340 (bool try_parse(const char *) [T = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128, 128, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type::unsigned_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type::unchecked, void>, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option::et_off>])
```

Comment: @cv_and_he seems related: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9007 and mailing list discussion http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Overflowing-the-integer-parser-td4650743.html